# How do I start working with Balana in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, balana

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG2Dd.png)[Balana error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RPWX.png) I'm working on eclipse Luna and I have added Maven to eclipse, and now I want to work with Balana to test some policies that I had written it.

I have edited pom file and added this dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.balana</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.balana</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I try to start w+orking with Balana, by writing this code:

private static Balana balana;

private static void initBalana() {

```
try{
        // using file based policy repository. so set the policy location as system property
        String policyLocation = (new File(".")).getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "resources";
        System.setProperty(FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.POLICY_DIR_PROPERTY, policyLocation);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Can not locate policy repository");
    }
    // create default instance of Balana
    balana = Balana.getInstance();
}
```

It gave so many errors on most of the code!

Edited:
First, it gave as the picture...
I had tried to solve it, but other errors had appeared.
As this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.wso2.balana.Balana.<clinit>(Balana.java:96)
at jar.AppTest.initBalana(AppTest.java:32)
at jar.AppTest.main(AppTest.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Any help... and Thanks...

Comment: Share the error messages

Comment: No mention of errors anywhere in the question. Also you should provide a minimum viable example for SO users to understand.

Comment: I have edited it, see it, please...

Answer (score 0):

As you have missing logfactory class in your classpath the above exception is thrown 
Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @AhmadSYousef check if commons-logging.jar exists in your classpath

Comment: I'll write POM.xml file, as you can see, this dependency is existed:

Comment: This file commons-logging.jar is not exist at all!

Comment: I've downloaded it from this website:https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi
and added it, but the same error  appears!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>doc-examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>Balana.testt</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.12</version>

  <name>Balana.testt</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.balana</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.balana</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.12</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```